# Using "if" to give custom error messages in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have just started to learn how to programm using c#
I am usin visual studio 2013 and I dont know the version of c#

Here I have a code to paint the background of command application

```
        for (; ; )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Give a number to select a colour between 0-15? ");
            ConsoleColor renk;
            renk = (ConsoleColor)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());




            Console.BackgroundColor = renk;
            Console.Clear();
        }
```

The thing is, when user gives any color, it paints the background, and loops to the start, so the user can type new one(number)

BUT

When the user just dont type a number and press enter, it just gives an error and crashes.
How can I show a message and loop it to  the start, when the user don't give a number?

I've tried this;

```
               if(renk)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("My error message!");

            }
```

But I don't know how to define "if "renk" is not defined"
Like, if I was trying to work this code when "renk" is < 5 
then I'd write;

```
         if(renk<5)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("My error message!");

            }


       else
            {

                bla bla bla

            }
```

Comment: What you want to do is to use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the input received from `ReadLine`, then check if the `TryParse` succeeeded to determine whether or not to output an error message.

Comment: when user dont enter a number or put some character and do enter, the function Convert.ToInt32 fails to convert the value to a number and throws an exception. Handle the exception.

Comment: You'll also want to include a range check (e.g. input is 0-15) to ensure only valid numbers are entered. And FYI, Visual Studio 2013 uses C# 5.0 with .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 4):

Use [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for checking string number inputs.
You will enter the "if" only if a number was inputted(and you will have the number in the num var).

```
for (; ; )
{
       Console.WriteLine("Give a number to select a colour between 0-15? ");
       ConsoleColor renk;
       int num;
       string strNum = Console.ReadLine();
       if(int.TryParse(strNum, out num) && (num >= 0 && num <= 15))
       {
            Console.BackgroundColor = (ConsoleColor)num;
            Console.Clear();
       }
       else
       {
             Console.WriteLine("Error");
       }  
}
```

Comment: As a new person to programming (Berque Cemilian) I wanted to make you aware of two important things (about this answer). First is that you'll notice this code assign the value of ReadLine() to a variable instead of passing the method directly to the `int.TryParse()` method.  This is advantageous because as you try to debug by stepping through the code, you can easily debug the value before it reaches the method.

Comment: The second thing is, that even though this adds another variable to the program which one could logically think makes the program bigger and/or use more memory, this is most likely not the case.  Compilers that take human readable code and turn it into computer readable code are extremely good about optimizing variables like this out.  The result is that you have easily debugable code and easily maintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

```
int inputNumber = 0;
for (; ; )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Give a number to select a colour between 0-15? ");
    ConsoleColor renk;

    if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out inputNumber) && (inputNumber>=0 && inputNumber<=15))
    {
        renk = (ConsoleColor)Convert.ToInt32(inputNumber);
        Console.BackgroundColor = renk;
        Console.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No Input Received! Quitting!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will still raise an exception if the input is not a number. Nor does it include validation for input 0-15.

Comment: @JWLim: Thanks, i didnt think about the text inout scenario, now edited my post.